# How to update an already existing value in oracle sql column

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to find possible solution on my question, but without success. Let say that I have a TEST table with many records and one of the columns is called CA_GROUP. That column contain the following values:

```
{"TEST1":"1","TEST2":"2"}
```

I want to add this part ',"TEST3":"3"' to the already existing values in that column. So the result should be as:

```
{"TEST1":"1","TEST2":"2","TEST3":"3"}
```

The only thing that I know is this:

```
update test t 
set t.ca_group = replace(t.ca:group, '{"TEST1":"1","TEST2":"2"}'
   , '{"TEST1":"1","TEST2":"2","TEST3":"3"}') 
where id = xxxxxx 
and other conditions.

update test t 
set t.ca_group = replace (t.ca:group, '{"CODE1":"1","CODE2":"2"}'
    , '{"CODE1":"1","CODE2":"2","TEST3":"3"}') 
where id = xxxxxx 
and other conditions.
```

But this is not efficient for me, because I have a lot of records and I need to add the same value in all columns one by one. Is there any smartest way of doing this ?

Comment: This is just not the right way to use a relational database. This is why relational database tables have "columns" !

Comment: So is this actually JSON docs or is the notation just a coincidence?

Answer (score 1):

How about appending 'TEST3' to each existing value?

```
update test t 
set t.ca_group = substr(t.ca_group, 1, length(t.ca_group) - 1) || ',"TEST3":"3"}'
where id = xxxxxx
```

Comment: `+` is not a valid string concatenator in Oracle. Use `||` . Also, `substr()` needs a starting offset.